# 自動生成したデータフレームを　繰り返し繋ぎ合わせる方法について教えてください。

Tags: python, pandas

例えば、下記のように繰り返しランダムにデータフレームxを自動生成し、
それを一つのデータフレームdfに自動的に繋げていく方法を教えてください。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i = 0
arr = []
for i in range(3):
    x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3))
    arr[i] = x
    df = merge([arr[0],arr[i]])

print(df)
```

---

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-3499f5327871> in <module>()
      6 for i in range(3):
      7     x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3))
----> 8     arr[i] = x
      9     df = merge([arr[0],arr[i]])
     10 

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: この辺を参考に。[Python pandas 図でみる データ連結 / 結合処理](http://sinhrks.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/01/28/073327), [pandasの使い方（merge、join、concat編）](http://pppurple.hatenablog.com/entry/2016/06/27/022310)　そもそも`arr`は要らないのでは？

Answer (score 1):

**更新：** こちらの方が少しだけシンプルかも

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = []
for i in range(3):
  x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3))
  arr.append(x)

df = pd.concat(arr, ignore_index=True)

print(arr)
print(df)
```

---

こんな処理で出来ます。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(3):
  x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3))
  df = pd.concat([df,x], ignore_index=True)

print(df)
```

---

ちなみに、後で何かに使うため個々の`DataFrame`も`arr[]`として残しておきたいと言った場合には、以下の様になります。

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

arr = []
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(3):
  x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3))
  arr.append(x)
  df = pd.concat([df,x], ignore_index=True)

print(arr)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

「一つのデータフレームdfに自動的に繋げていく方法」
ですが, どのような結果を望むのか書いてないので適当に行います

- "9 x 1"
- "3 x 3" (getting longer, getting wider どちらか)
- "1 x 9"

別の回答に, "9 x 1" の構築があるので, ここでは "3 x 3" で。
・・・ 3カラムの DataFrameを, 行数分繋げる方法

質問のコードでは `merge`が使われてるけど, これは keyや idを利用して結び付けるもので
今回のように index増やすだけの操作には `concat` を使います

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#!pip install perfplot
import perfplot

row, col = (1000, 3)

def concat(r):
    """毎回 pd.concat()
    最初に空の DataFrame用意し, 継ぎ足していく
    """
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for n in range(r):
        x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(col)).T
        df = pd.concat([df, x], axis=0)
    return df

def concat_arr(r):
    """最後に一度だけ pd.concat()
    arr: list 用意し, 毎回それに追加し
    最後に連結(concat)する
    """
    arr = []
    for n in range(r):
        x = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(col)).T
        arr.append(x)
    return pd.concat(arr, axis=0)

def series_concat(r):
    """Series を使う (1)
    一次元データの Seriesを使い, arr に追加していき
    最後に連結(concat)する
    """
    arr = []
    for n in range(r):
        ser = pd.Series(np.random.rand(col))
        arr.append(ser)
    return pd.concat(arr, axis=1).T

def series_df(r):
    """Series を使う (2)
    一次元データの Seriesを使い, arr に追加していき
    最後に DataFrameを作り出す
    """
    arr = []
    for n in range(r):
        ser = pd.Series(np.random.rand(col))
        arr.append(ser)
    return pd.DataFrame(arr)

def np_rand(r):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(r, col))


out = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: n,
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(10)],
    kernels=[
        concat,
        concat_arr,
        series_concat,
        series_df,
        # np_rand,
    ],
    equality_check=lambda r1, r2: r1.shape == r2.shape,
    xlabel="row(r)",
)
out.show()
#out.save("out.svg")
```

[image: 結果のベンチマーク]

---

DataFrameライブラリーはちまちま追加していくと遅くなります
(すべての DataFrameライブラリー知るわけではないが, そのような傾向にあると思います)
このため, 最後にまとめて `concat` 行うほうがよいでしょう

`Series`が高速なのは, DataFrameの構造上, カラムを追加していくほうが速いためでしょう(たぶん)

何のためにこのような追加を行いたいか不明だけど
一番高速なのは, 上のコードの `np_rand` です
(もしくは NumPy の NDArray を先に, 必要分用意しておいて, DataFrame作成)
設計時に, このように, DataFrame 追加せずに済むようにするのが望ましいかも